# "FATAL: You must configure a GitHub token"

Tags: gitlab, renovate

I'm trying to install renovate on a self-hosted GitLab instance. I installed renovate to my Node.js project via the following command: `npm install renovate@latest`

Then I created a `renovate.json` file and inserted the following configuration:

```
{
    "token": "my-gitlab-token",
    "platform": "gitlab",
    "gitlabHost": "https://my-self-hosted-gitlab.com",
    "onboarding": true,
    "baseBranches": ["master"],
    "automerge": false,
    "packageRules": [
        {
        "packageNames": ["*"],
        "automerge": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Then when I try to run renovate via the following command: `npx renovate`
I get this error:

```
FATAL: You must configure a GitHub token
 INFO: Renovate is exiting with a non-zero code due to the following logged errors
       "loggerErrors": [
         {
           "name": "renovate",
           "level": 60,
           "logContext": "QEWpdMHBUx3OqqQYbsThL",
           "msg": "You must configure a GitHub token"
         }
       ]
```

I tried to run `npx renovate init` but it get the same error. I also tried to create a `.renovaterc.json` file that contains the same configuration. Same error.

I don't understand why renovate does not find my config file. And why renovate thinks I'm using github even though I'm using gitlab.
I run the command in the same path as my config file is located. And when I try to add the flag `--config` to my command, renovate returns:
`error: unknown option '--config'`

Comment: Please tell me you read the error?

Comment: The file should be named `config.json`. Also you can set the env variable `LOG_LEVEL=debug` to troubleshoot why Renovate isn't picking your config file.

Comment: (Indeed, when using Gitlab, the GitHub token is not mandatory)

Comment: @GaëlJ I still have the same issue after renaming my config file `config.json`. And the debug variable does not give me more result.

Comment: Can you share the complete logs somehow?

Comment: I meant `config.js`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this documentation: https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/blob/main/docs/usage/getting-started/running.md#global-config

> By default Renovate checks if a file named config.js is present. Any other (*.js, *.json, *.json5, *.yaml or *.yml) file is supported, when you reference it with the `RENOVATE_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable

If the configuration file is not named `config.js` and present in the current directory, you need to give the configuration file location via the `RENOVATE_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable.

You can then launch renovate like this:

```bash
RENOVATE_CONFIG_FILE=renovate.json npx renovate
```

Comment: As per this same documentation, naming the file `config.json` is the default and you shouldn't need the env variable.

Comment: Quoting the documentation: "By default Renovate checks if a file named config.js is present. Any other (*.js, *.json, *.json5, *.yaml or *.yml) file is supported, **when you reference it with the RENOVATE_CONFIG_FILE environment variable**"

Comment: I meant `config.js`